Logs not getting sent to Datadog when running Django shell inside a container
The logs that are created by the code running inside the container do get sent to Datadog, but when I'm in a shell session inside the container those logs get outputted in the terminal, but not sent to Datadog. Therefore, once I leave the session (if I don't copy and paste the logs into a file), they are forever lost.
TL;DR; Datadog Agent runs inside the container, but not inside the shell session inside the container
How can I make it so that the logs produced inside the shell session also get sent to Datadog ?

What is your log setup like, and how is Datadog collecting logs?

With @Vergard can you please show the code that executes the log storage in Datadog? I'm not quite understanding, if you get into bash in a container, you are using the container's environment so you should have access to the build and all packages used within
